# How can I attach a FileList to an input type file

Tags: javascript, forms, file, input, drag-and-drop

I'd like to attach in JS or jQuery a FileList (retrieved from a drag and drop event) to an input of type "file". Is it possible ?

thank for your help :)

Comment: you have an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) and [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to send the file(s) to the server somewhat like this:

```
// Create new form data to send to the server
let formData = new FormData()

// Attach a file
formData.append('file', document.querySelector('input[type=file]'))

// Attach an input file
formData.append('title', document.querySelector('#file-title'))

// Send the form data
fetch('/path/to/endpoint', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it like that, it works perfectly ;)

```
//We are in the drop event scope
var FileListRetrievedFromDropEvent = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
var myInput = document.querySelector('#myInputFile');
myInput.files = FileListRetrievedFromDropEvent;
```